# Group/collapse rows in a true Excel table?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

In Excel, we can create a table in a sheet ([Overview of Excel tables](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/overview-of-excel-tables-7ab0bb7d-3a9e-4b56-a3c9-6c94334e492c)):

[image]

---

Question:

Is it possible to **group/collapse** rows in an Excel table  -- similar to [Excel outlines](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/outline-group-data-in-a-worksheet-08ce98c4-0063-4d42-8ac7-8278c49e9aff)?

[image]

Comment: What you've tried? What do you exactly need (group whole table...)?

Comment: Proper result depends on data set structure,, but YES you can apply Group and Subtotal on TABLE also.

Comment: @MátéJuhász I want to manually group rows based on a single text field. Example: group rows where `DIVISION = Fleet` into one group, and group rows where `DIVISION = Facilities` into another group.

Comment: @RajeshS -- When I group some rows in the table it works fine. But then when I try to group adjacent rows into a separate group, it just merges the rows into the previous/adjacent group, which is not what I want.

Comment: @User1973 , if possible share the sheet n cloud an let me try,, also write down what exactly U are expecting .

Answer (score 2):

I can group rows in a table as normal：

Go to the Data tab > Outline group, click the arrow under Group, and select Auto Outline.

[image]

More information:

https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2017/12/28/excel-group-rows/

Comment: Thanks. When I group some rows in the table it works fine. But then when I try to group adjacent rows into a separate group, it just merges the rows into the previous/adjacent group, which is not what I want. Frustrating!

Comment: @user1973 that issue is probably not related to the table. Try skipping one row during grouping (header row will be added to your selection anyway)